# jQuery Datatable XHR and Error event together not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

Can someone please let me know whether xhr.dt and error.dt will work together. For me only xhr.dt event working at a time. If I disable xhr.dt event, thenerror.dt start working.

As per the documentation ([xhr event](https://datatables.net/reference/event/xhr#Type))

> Since 1.10.7 you can return true to indicate to DataTables that it
>   should not trigger its error event if you have handled an error
>   condition yourself.

Bit confusion is here and not clear about returning flag to make enable error.dt event.

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 0):

Seems like XHR.dt event will be fired on AJAX request success or fail. The call success or fail should be handled in xhr.dt event. Since the error is captured by xhr.dt first err.dt will not be triggered.

Hope it makes sense.